# R using string variable for column name

Tags: r, variables

I am new to R and have am having trouble understanding how to substitute a variable name for column name.  For example, the code below works fine finding the row with the max value for col2 with defined column names

```
> df<-data.frame(name=sample(LETTERS[1:5]),val1=sample(5), val2=sample(5))
> df
  name val1 val2
1    B    3    1
2    C    4    3
3    E    5    2
4    D    2    4
5    A    1    5
> df[which(df$val2 == max(df$val2)),]
5    A    1    5
```

But if I cannot seem to get this work with a string variable for the column name such as

```
colName = "val2"
```

Comment: `df[which(df[,colName]==max(df[,colName])),]`

Comment: See also [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18222286/select-a-data-frame-column-using-and-the-name-of-the-column-in-a-variable/)

Comment: "$ is a shorthand operator, where `x$y` is equivalent to `x[["y", exact = FALSE]]`" http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Subsetting.html. You see for instance `mtcars$cy` is same as `mtcars$cyl`

Comment: Thanks guys for the pointers.  I have some much to learn about R.